# Having problems in understanding this multivariable problem example

Tags: multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions, random-variables, uniform-distribution, random-functions

So the problem says:
Inside interval [0,1] dot (a) is fixated.

Random variable X is uniformly distributed on interval [0,1].

What is the covariance moment between X and variable Y = |x-a| : distance from X to a.
So this is the solution : https://i.stack.imgur.com/nG46X.jpg.

Now I understand E(x) of course, $\int_0^1 x* 1$ = 1/2.
but what about E(y). why did we integrate (a - x)from 0 to a  and then integrate (x - a) from a to 1. Can someone explain E(Y) to me please.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$|x-a|=\begin{cases}
x-a & x\geq a\\
a-x & x\leq a
\end{cases},$$

so to compute the mean of $Y$, they use [LOTUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) and integrate piecewise:

$$E[|X-a|]=\int_0^1 |x-a|dx=\int_0^a (a-x) dx+\int_a^1 (x-a)dx.$$

Comment: So what I don't understand is this: If E(Y) = y * F(Y), where is y here, after that, we know that F(Y)  = P(Y < y), so we are looking when Y will be less than y, we have that when the  distance of x to a is less than that of y, so wouldnt the solution for F(Y) be integral from x to a of ( (a - x)  )when x>=a and integral from a to x of (x-a) when x <= a?

Comment: @curious Not sure I follow what you are saying.  The expected value of a random variable $Z$ having density $f_Z(z)$ is defined as $E[Z]=\int_{\mathbb{R}}z f_Z(z)dz.$ 
 Using this definition directly on $Y$ would require finding the density for $Y$, but since we know $Y$ is a function of $X$, it turns out computing the expected value can be done via LOTUS.

Comment: @curious Pls see the wiki link on LOTUS, but it allows us to integrate using the density of $X$ to compute the expected value for $Y$. And since $X$ takes on values with positive density on $(0,1)$, we use these bounds for the integral.

Comment: Thank you for answering, can you explain to me a bit more, how did we chose in from where to where to integrate (borders?)

Comment: $X$ is uniform on $(0,1)$, correct? Since I am integrating with respect to values $X$ takes on, the integration limits are $(0,1)$. I then split up the integral piecewise to deal with the fact that the function $|x-a|$ has different expressions depending on the value of $x$.

Comment: Outside the interval $(0,1)$, the density of $X$ is zero

Comment: hopefully makes more sense?